# How the wildcards works in Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I am reading the java tutorial about Wildcards in Generics. In the following code:

```
void printCollection(Collection<Object> c) {
    for (Object e : c) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Does this means the collection `c` take type `object` as its elements, and we can not call `c.add("apple")`,
because "apple" is a string and the for loop takes any `object` elements from collection `c`?

But I do not understand the following code,

```
void printCollection(Collection<?> c) {
    for (Object e : c) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

This code uses wildcards, meaning "a collection whose element type matches anything." Does this mean we can add any type of object to it, such as `c.add("string");`,
`c.add(1);`, and  `c.add(new apple());` ?
and the for loop take any object `e` from collection `c`, if `c` is not an `object` type, we say `c`'s elements are Integer. Does this code works? Does this mean it should be cast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got it almost exactly backwards.

A `Collection<Object>` can contain `Object` and subclasses of it, and since everything (including `String`) is a subclass of `Object`, you can add anything to such a collection. However, you cannot make any assumptions about its contents except that they're `Object`s.

On the other hand, A `Collection<?>` contains only instances of a specific *unknown* type (and its subclasses), but since you don't know *which* type it is, you cannot add anything (except `null`) to such a collection, nor make any assumptions about its conents (except that they're `Object`s, because everything is).

Answer (score 0):

In [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html), question "What is the difference between the unbounded wildcard parameterized type and the raw type?" ([link](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ303)) you'll see that `Collection<?>` and `Collection<Object>` are almost equivalent.

Comment: They're not equivalent at all when it comes to adding things to them.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the second statement the "?" wildcard means that the generic is not defined. The result is that the type is bound to "Object" because this is the default bound for no declaration.

In fact even "Integer" is a subclass of Object. If you mean "int" you are right, thats a primitive and not a derivate of Object, but you can't put it into a Collection, since a Collection only allows derivates of Object.

And to the question if the elements put into the collection should be casted. No, thats not necessary since they are clear derivate classes from Object. The compiler does not need any explicit cast information there, he resolves the right class definition automatically.